# https://example.com is not getting resolved

Tags: dns, cname

I'm supporting a client which is having an issue with their naked domain not getting resolved when requested through https.(https://example.com)

**All of these other url are resolved:**

- http://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com

**DNS Setup**

1. In their dns settings. The example.com is forwarded to http://www.example.com
2. A record is not pointing to the actual IP of the web server instead is pointing to the IP of the DNS provider. (I think this is the default when they bought the domain).
3. CNAME www is then pointing to their Azure DNS hostname (*.cloudapp.net) which contains their company DNS records. (forwarding the request to another name server by CNAME)

**What I've tried:**

1. pointed the A record to the correct web server IP and now the https://example.com is getting resolved.

**Questions:**

1. Why is the https://example.com was not getting resolved?
2. Is the CNAME forwarding to another name server a correct setup instead of just changing the name servers to Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why is the https://example.com was not getting resolved? - This is because the A record has to point to an IP address of the web server pointing it to the IP address of the DNS server is wrong, until you have the same ip address serving http requests and dns requests both.
2. My guess is that *.cloudapp.net is the domain where the actual application is hosted instead of DNS hostname. A CNAME can point to another hostname is perfectly fine, provided the another hostname resolves to the correct destination server ip address.

Comment: This answer my questions. Wanted to validate if my assumptions are correct. thanks